# Cypress: Get token from API then save in local storage and use in another API's header then return the response body of the 2nd API

Tags: javascript, json, automated-tests, cypress

I have an API (let's call it **getToken**) to generate a token in its response body. I then call that token and store in the header of another API (let's call it **returnBody**). It makes sense to use `localStorage` for the **getToken** API as this token is re-usable for multiple API's. However, I am having doubts using `localStorage` if I need to return / display the response body of the succeeding API's such as **returnBody**. Inside the API's function/command, it logs the response body. However, when I call it via the test file, it generates **null**.
Sample code below:

***commands.js:***

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getToken', () => { //API to generate token
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://someAPItoGenerateToken',
        form: true, //sets to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        body: {
            grant_type: 'credentials',
            scope: 'all-apis'
        },
        auth: {
            username: Cypress.env('api_username'),
            password: Cypress.env('api_password')
        }
    })
        .its('body')
        .then(bearerToken => {
            cy.setLocalStorage('bearerToken', JSON.stringify(bearerToken))
            cy.log('Token generated: ' + bearerToken.token)
            }
        )
})

Cypress.Commands.add('returnBody', (url, token) => { //API to return some values
    return cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        auth: {
            bearer: token
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            // Stringify JSON the body.
            let body = JSON.stringify(response.body)
            cy.log(body)
        })
})
```

***test file:***

```
describe('Return value of 2nd API', ()=> {
    before(() => {
        cy.getToken() //Run this once to generate token for the entire test suite
        cy.saveLocalStorage()
    })

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.restoreLocalStorage()
    })

    it('Return value of 2nd API', () => {
        cy.getLocalStorage('bearerToken').should('exist')
        cy.getLocalStorage('bearerToken').then(bearerToken => {
            const tokenJSON = JSON.parse(bearerToken)
            const url = 'https://someAPItoReturnJSONbody'
            cy.returnBody(url, tokenJSON.token).then((returned_value) => {
                cy.log(returned_value)
            })
        })

    })
})
```

**body** from the returnBody command returns the JSON response. However, **returned_value** from the test file displays null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented in [this issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/435): "You cannot return a 3rd party promise from a custom command because this breaks the chaining between cypress commands. This is because the .then methods are not the same."

So, simply return the request body as:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('returnBody', (url, token) => {
  return cy.request({ /* options */ })
    .its("body");
});
```

Then, in your test you can do:

```js
it("should return foo value", () => {
  cy.returnBody(url, token).then(returned_value => {
    cy.log(returned_value);
    expect(returned_value).to.deep.equal("foo-value");
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks @javier-brea but this still returns null value in my test file:             `cy.returnBody(url, tokenJSON.token).then((returned_value) => {cy.log(returned_value)})`.

Comment: Sorry @er123, you're right, returning a Promise was not working. I've found the solution here https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/435 . I have edited the example, tested it, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to return response body from your `returnBody` task:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('returnBody', (url, token) => {
  return cy.request({ /* options */ })
    .then(response => {
      let body = JSON.stringify(response.body);
      Cypress.log(body);
      return body; // Add this line
    });
});
```

Comment: I get this error: CypressError: cy.then() failed because you are mixing up async and sync code.

Comment: @er123 try to replace `cy.log()` with `Cypress.log()`

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with the command 'log'. Even so, I tried it and get this error: **CypressError: Cypress.log() can only be called with an options object.Your argument was: 'null'.**  Also, sorry to be frank but your initial solution seems anti-pattern with one returning the whole cypress command (cy.request) then inside, return again on the value (body).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to store the token on cypress side using fixtures.

*fixture.json:*

```
{"bearerToken":""
.
.
.}
```

*commands.js:*

```
cy.fixture('testData.json').as('testData')
.
.
.then(bearerToken => {
            this.testData.bearerToken = JSON.stringify(bearerToken)
            cy.log('Token generated: ' + bearerToken.token)
            }
        )
```

*test.js*

```
describe('Return value of 2nd API', ()=> {
    before(() => {
        cy.getToken() //Run this once to generate token for the entire test suite
    })

    it('Return value of 2nd API', () => {
        cy.fixture('testData.json').as('testData')
        .then(testData => {
            const tokenJSON = JSON.parse(testData.bearerToken)
            const url = 'https://someAPItoReturnJSONbody'
            cy.returnBody(url, tokenJSON.token).then((returned_value) => {
                cy.log(returned_value)
            })
        })

    })
})
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this initially using `cy.writeFile` but my runs became a bit unstable. I had to set `watchForFileChanges` to `false` as well. While this is another good alternative but for my use case, I want it to run faster and this method may affect performance as I need to keep calling the token and this will keep updating the fixture file, which is another layer I am not too keen of using at this stage.